# Sign hash using CADES-BES signature using USB token use php

Tags: php, json, certificate

under the regulation of the e-invoicing in Egypt, the invoices must be electronically signed before submission. I have been trying to follow the steps in there website: here but I dont have much experience in this field and I dont find enough resources in that link to create the e-signature from the usb token on the hashed value. Iam use php.
Thank you

Don't need chilckat i need php code